# Android - apptheme of AppCompat while extending Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-appcompat

My base appTheme looks like this:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
```

but all  my Activities extend `import android.app.Activity;` So they all extend a base class that looks like this:

```
public class BaseActivity extends Activity {
...
}
```

Lint recommended me to change the base class to extend AppCompatActivity instead. Is this necessary, **what kind of issues can i face if i fail to change this but continue to use the theme?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `AppCompatActivity` is a support library class that allows applications to use the `ActionBar` all the way back to api level 7.

I would recommend extending this class instead of the `android.app.Activity.`, especially if you are using that particular theme. You would run into issues if you did not extend the `AppCompatActivity` while using that particular theme.

Here's a link to additional documentation on it.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html